# Redirect page but keep original page cached to go back to

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have what is basically a hidden form building up a query through dynamically created fields.

When I hit the results button it redirects me to another page showing the results.

The redirect url includes get variables that I process on the results page to get the data I need.

The whole thing is done using jquery to build the form dynamically - each image click adds a class to the image to highlight that its been selected.

All good - apart from that if I want to get back from the results page to edit my inputted criteria - I loose everything.

I have tried:     window.history.go(-1) but it doesn't remember my settings

is it possible to cache the page to go back to or store the entire pages html as a session

open to ideas as not sure how to tackle

Comment: It caches the page as it was after it has been loaded, not after changes you made. To keep track of that you have to send them back or to store them somewhere (local storage, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use localStorage on HTML5 for that purpose. Just save via JS before redirection and check on page load if there is data available.
Alternatively you could submit the form and save it in a session on the server.

What I personally prefer are pages which don't change location at all but use JS to load (new) content. This would make it possible to just save the form data to a JS variable - but you would have to restructure your site a bit.